# Receive forbidden message when trying to access my website

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403, port80

When trying to load my website I receive the following message.

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at www.xxx.com Port 80

Please note I am complete novice to this so any guidance would be amazing!!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please read the guide on how to ask a question. We are missing some details.

Comment: I am trying to access my website but it is not working, get the error message above when I try to access it. The whole of my website is basically down

Comment: Was it working before? What did you change? Are you using PHP or something else? Maybe provide your VHost config and which path it is that you try to access (you've stated the whole website to be down, so I assume now that no path is working).

Comment: Yes, it was working before. I changed the billing account, so removed the project from one billing account and then assigned it to a new one. Would this cause any issues? Sorry, i'm really new to all this - I don't know what PHP means. 
And yes, no path is working

Comment: This could be the cause of your troubles, indeed. Which interface did you use? ISPConfig? Plesk? cPanel? Liveconfig? Does there ring a bell for any of these names? Maybe you deactivated some necessary features the old account had. Maybe you also have to login via FTP and change Path permissions like stated in the answers, but usually your interface will do that for you.

Comment: I did it in the Google Cloud Platform. None of those ring a bell unfortunately. Sorry, how would I log in via FTP?

Comment: That you are using GCP is an interesting fact... Did you try the troubleshooting mentioned here? https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/troubleshooting It has a 403 section

Comment: I had the experience of getting the Forbidden message web page when developing my web app.    The problem was that some of the top level files in my web app were missing, including the initial html file.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information; A couple of possible things to look at:

1) 
Check permissions on the directory you are hosting the web files (usually under /var/www). See this link for adding your user to www-data group etc..

https://askubuntu.com/questions/162866/correct-permissions-for-var-www-and-wordpress

2) 
Issue in Apache config. Discussed here:
[WAMP : Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337917/wamp-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server-apache-2)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the permission of that directory in which you have your project files

type chmod 777 directory-name